# Decomposition of a Hilbert space by a finite-dimensional subspace. Fredholm operators

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a Hilbert space.

> **Proposition.** For a finite-dimensional subspace $V$, there exists a closed subspace $F$ such that $A=V\oplus F$, i.e., $V\cap F$ is the trivial space and $V+F=A$

*Question*: When is the subspace $F$ the orthogonal complement of $V$?

My interest in the above result comes from the theory of Fredholm operators. For a Fredholm operator $F:A\to B$ between Hilbert spaces, the above result implies:
$$B=T(A)\oplus B'$$
for certain $B'$ closed and finite-dimensional subspace. If the orthogonal complement of $V$ coincides with $B'$ then it follows that:
$$B=T(A)\oplus T(A)^\perp=T(A)\oplus \ker T^\star,$$
where $T^\star$ is the formal adjoint. This is precisely the equality that I have looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expect every direct sum to be an orthogonal sum, as such a thing already fails in dimension $2$: $$\mathbb C^2=\mathbb C(1,0)\oplus\mathbb C(1,1)$$ is a direct sum which is not an orthogonal sum.

Now, given any subspace $K$ of a Hilbert space $H$, you always have $H=\overline K\oplus K^\perp$. In particular, if $T:A\to B$, you always have
$$
B=\overline{TA}\oplus(TA)^\perp.
$$
And since for a bounded operator $T$ you always have $(TA)^\perp=\ker T^*$, the equality
$$
B=\overline{TA}\oplus\ker T^*
$$
holds for any $T\in B(A,B)$. Finally, since every Fredholm operator has closed range,
$$
B={TA}\oplus\ker T^*
$$
holds for any Fredholm operator $T:A\to B$.